# What is the difference between List<Number> and List<? extends Number>?

Tags: java, generics

I have a very basic question ragarding **Java generics** . I thought that both `List<Number>` and `List<? extends Number>` are homogeneous . Am I right or is there something fundamental I am missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generic types are more pedantic.

`<? extends Number>` means Number or an unknown a sub class. If you obtain such a value it will be a `Number`, but you cannot give a value of this type because you don't know which is valid.

The difference is in arguments and return values.

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
Number n = 1;
numbers.add(n); // ok.
n = numbers.get(0); // ok
numbers.add(1); // ok.

List<? extends Number> numbers2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
numbers2.add(n); // not ok
n = numbers2.get(0); // ok

List<? super Number> numbers3 = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
numbers3.add(n); // ok
n = numbers3.get(0); // not ok.
```

---

`super` is used in a few places to signify the type can be a super type. e.g.

In Collections, this method says the Comparator needs to be able to compare the same type or any super type.

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

This means you can have

```
Comparator<Number> comparesAnyNumbers = ...
List<Integer> ints = ...
Collections.sort(ints, comparesAnyNumbers);
```

Comment: They are more specific, `<Number>` means just Number not some other type as well.

Comment: Could you provides details on the usefullness of `List<? super Number>` ?

Comment: IMHO Its not terribly useful. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey getting compilation issue for `numbers2.add(new Integer(2)); `? this should work right?

Comment: @Nandkumar No, numbers2 is actually an `ArrayList<Double>`

Comment: @PeterLawrey : I used diamond `<>` there, no <Double>.

Comment: @PeterLawrey from the compiler perspective, number2 is a `List<? extends Number>` not a `ArrayList<Double>`. The instruction `numbers2.add(Double.valueOf(1d));` don't work too.

Comment: @gontard Correct, the point is; the list contains a unknown type which extends Number.

Comment: @PeterLawrey nothing (but `null`) could be added into `List<? extends Number>` ?

Comment: `List<? extends T>` : since we don't what is really `?` : you can't **add** item into it : this is a sort of `"read-only compile time checked list"`.

Comment: `List<? super T>` : since we don't what is really `?` : you can't **read** item from it : this is a sort of `"write-only compile time checked list"`.

Comment: @gontard Sort of but you can call `remove(0);` or `clear();` on it. ;)

Comment: @gontard You can read an `Object` from `? super T` as every object is an `Object`

Comment: @gontard `const` is a keyword in Java, you just can't use it anywhere. :D

Comment: @PeterLawrey may be in `java 10` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Generics are compile time language features, means, they don't exist in run-time. 
In generic mechanism, for compile-time checks, they are not homogeneous, i.e. if you want to use polymorphism in generic type.

Following gives you a compile time error, although it seems a valid definition:

```
 List<Number> list = new ArrayList <Integer>();
```

whereas

```
 List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList <Integer>();
```

is valid. Moreover, you can't use wildcard types on the right side:

```
 List list = new ArrayList <? extends Integer>();
```

won't be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

`List<Number>`           --> List of `Number`s (or instances of `Number`)

`List<? extends Number>` --> List any type which extends `Number`