# Guice generic binding interface to implementation bounded type parameter

Tags: java, generics, guice

I am developing a JAX-RS based Java application using Google Guice for dependency injection. I have the following interface in my code:

```
public interface LockProvider<L extends Lock> {
    Optional<L> acquireLock(String lockId);

    void releaseLock(L lock);
}
```

In the above interface, Lock is an interface defined as follows:

```
public interface Lock {
    String getLockId();
}
```

Lock interface is implemented by the following class:

```
public class DynamoDBLock implements Lock {
    private final String lockId;
    private final LockItem underLyingLock;

    public DynamoDBLock(final String lockId, final LockItem underLyingLock) {
    this.lockId = lockId;
    this.underLyingLock = underLyingLock;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLockId() {
        return lockId;
    }

    public LockItem getUnderlyingLock() {
        return underlyingLock;
    }
}
```

LockProvider interface is implemented by the following class:

```
public class DynamoDBLockProvider implements LockProvider<DynamoDBLock> {
    Optional<DynamoDBLock> acquireLock(String lockId) {
        //implementation here
    }

    void releaseLock(DynamoDBLock lock) {
        LockItem underlyingLockItem = lock.getUnderlyingLockItem();
        //do something with underlyingLockItem
    }
}
```

I don't want classes in my application other than LockProvider to know about underLying lock item, which is why I haven't included getUnderlyingLockItem in the Lock interface.

Now, when I try to bind LockProvider to DynamoDBLockProvider as follows:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<LockProvider<Lock>>() {}).to(DynamoDBLockProvider.class);
```

I get the following compilation error in Eclipse:

```
The method to(Class<? extends LockProvider<Lock>>) in the type LinkedBindingBuilder<LockProvider<Lock>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<DynamoDBLockProvider>)
```

**I understand that DynamoDBLockProvider<DynamoDBLock> is not a subclass of LockProvider<Lock>. Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying to do, i.e. bind LockProvider to DynamoDBLockProvider (in a clean and efficient way)?**

Comment: The solution worked for me. I edited for completeness; I had forgotten to escape less than and greater than signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instances of `DynamoDBLockProvider` are **not** instances of `LockProvider<Lock>`. But they **are** instances of `LockProvider<? extends Lock>`.

A parallel example would be instances of `ArrayList<Integer>` are **not** instances of `List<Number>` but **are** instances of `List<? extends Number>` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216326/what-is-the-difference-between-listnumber-and-list-extends-number).

Apply that to Guice and you will get exactly the same compilation fail. Assume you have a class like this:

```
public class IntegerList extends ArrayList<Integer> {}
```

Then binding it like this won't work:

```
binder.bind(new TypeLiteral<List<Number>>() {}).to(IntegerList.class); //won't compile
```

> Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying to do, i.e. bind LockProvider to DynamoDBLockProvider (in a clean and efficient way)?

The following binding will work:

```
binder.bind(new TypeLiteral<LockProvider<? extends Lock>>() {}).to(DynamoDBLockProvider.class);
```